# Make Outlook show calendar notifications in the Windows 10 notification bar

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, office365

I have Microsoft Outlook 365 running on Windows 10. When I get new emails, they appear in the notification bar on the right of my screen. But calendar notifications pop up a window that must be dismissed. Can I get these calendar notifications to show up like emails do?

Answer (score 4):

we can set the account up in Windows Mail app, turning off sync for mail and contacts.

Calendar reminders will use the Windows reminder system and display prominently in the corner of your screen, on top of any open programs.

[image]

Please refer to the steps below:

1. Add your Exchange account to Mail app. Win 10 will automatically configure this account on Calendar App too.
2. Open Start > Settings > System > Notification&Actions.
3. Turn on notifications for Outlook and Calendar but turn off the option for Mail.

[image]

Reference [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1b393f16-d655-4b76-9d8b-ab500b3f6e02/missing-appointmentsmeetings?forum=outlook)

Comment: To avoid receiving duplicated notification, we may turn off outlook reminders: Go to File > Options > Advanced > Reminder section. Untick "Show Reminders".

Comment: I feel (I can't state it as fact) that Windows Update sometimes overwrites thes preferences. If not Windows Update then perhaps it's a Group Policy change or the like. It is frustrating to have to continually correct this, especially since it's long forgotten by the time it happens again. I am becoming a Windows hater :(

Comment: If your answer were more concise and to the point, I suspect it might be accepted.

Comment: This is a good answer, but Microsoft is apparently discontinuing support for Calendar in 2024: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook/mail-amp-calendar-apps-will-be-replaced-with-new-outlook-for/m-p/3850309